# Retrieve NMEA data in windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, gps, windows-mobile-6

I want retrieve data from my integrated gps hardware..i've read more post on stackoverflow but  i don't found the c# source code. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see my GPSsample here http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/06/11/enhanced-gps-sample-update/

The clue to get the raw NMEA data is to use the GPSID direct port. It is encoded in the regitrsy:

```
        private string GetGPSPort()
    {
        string szStr="";
        if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM,
                        "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Multiplexer",
                        "DriverInterface",
                        ref szStr)
            == 0)
        {
            return szStr;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM,
                "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers",
                "CurrentDriver",
                ref szStr) == 0)
            {
                string szPath = "System\\CurrentControlSet\\GPS Intermediate Driver\\Drivers\\" + szStr;
                if (Registry.GetStringValue(Registry.HKLM, szPath, "CommPort", ref szStr) == 0)
                {
                    return szStr;
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The above gives the port name you can use to open and read the RAW NMEA data.

The above assumes the device supports MS GPSID.

Further there are two possiblities to use the raw port: a) using Serial communication or b) using a stream. Both access and read methods are used in the full source code available via the web site.

Comment: thaks for answer. i cant try the code why i have just find the COM port of my integrated GPS. For retrieve data i use the SerialPort component... On DataReceived event i parse the NMEA string! thanks....

Comment: as written, SerialPort component may be unsuitable if the GPS driver only supports streaming!